# How do I make a domain go to a specific port?

Tags: domain, website, web-hosting

So let's say I have a domain eg. xyz.abc.uk, but since typing my external IP address redirects to my router settings on port 80 (let's say i use port 1234) how can I make it so xyz.abc.uk uses port 80 without using redirects? 
Thanks

Comment: Does this happen from inside your LAN, or from outside, or both?

Comment: I want it so that everyone (inside and outside my lan) can connect to the website with the port.

Comment: Not what I asked... You said "typing my external IP address redirects to my router settings on port 80", does this _currently_ happen from inside or from outside?

Comment: only through my lan does it redirect to my router, but from the outside that means it would just display errors

Comment: From the outside it should follow port forwarding (I hope you have set that up in your router). For the inside you would need a split DNS that gives the local IP address of the webserver (or enter the local IP address and name into /etc/hosts everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

> Typing my external IP address redirects to my router settings on port 80.

The first thing I would do would be to set up port forwarding on the router to your local server and then test again. Even if the issue you are encountering persists, you will likely need to take this step anyway.

If the issue isn't resolved, you will probably want to set up a local DNS server to handle `xyz.abc.uk` on your network. You would need to set up this DNS server so that:

- It sent requests for `xyz.abc.uk` to the local network address for your server.
- It forwarded all requests for sites *other* than `xyz.abc.uk` to another set of DNS servers (such as those run by your ISP).
- It was the default DNS server used by your router for your network.

The alternative to this would be to set the `hosts` file on every device on your network to forward `xyz.abc.uk` to the address of your local server.